# Resizing an imageview's width/height greater or lesser upon a button click?

Tags: android, image, resize, imageview

Would this work for changing an imageview's size? Doing something such as:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
relativeLayout.addView(image);
```

...
Then upon button click have this happen:

```
image.getLayoutParams().width = image.getLayoutParams().width - 10;
```

I click my button but nothing seems to happen. Why? What's the correct way to go about manually resizing an imageview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getLayoutParams() is a **method**. So, you're going to have to add opening and closing parentheses when you call it. Try this instead

```
image.getLayoutParams().width = image.getLayoutParams().width - 10;
```

Or simply

```
image.getLayoutParams().width -= 10;
```

Edit: Try it like this

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
params.width = params.width - 10;
image.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: yeah sorry I tried that and it didn't work still haha. Just forgot the paranthesis in my question

Comment: See if my edit works for you. By the way, why do you have this line `relativeLayout.addView(image);` ? Are you creating a relativeLayout programmatically?

Comment: your edit seemed to work only the problem is that the params.width seems to start at 0 for some reason? So my image will start very small then incrementally get bigger. Was wanting to make it grow from its original width or height. And no, my parent layout is in my .xml. I'm just calling it so I can add the image programatically. edit: Sorry, I should add that I'm currently ADDING to the width. And it does that. When I SUBTRACT from the width it also starts at 0 but doesn't get smaller since it's already at 0. Strange.

Comment: Only the bottom 3 lines should be inside of your button click method. The `ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);` should be inside of your onCreate() . Did you do that?

Comment: Ohhh ok, I think that might be the problem. Currently, I'm setting the imageview to null and set it to a resource when you select from a variety of images in a scrollview. Then that image is displayed in the relativelayout. So I think my button is taking the layouts of the originally called ImageView before its set? Instead of the one after it's set?

Comment: Yes, that's probably it. You should maybe set some sort of a default image.